# use same action in different pages in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have 2 pages, all having the same search function, so I want use the same action name for 2 page search. The problem is when validation failed, how to define result='input' back to different pages?

Is there any solution to this? Or do we have to define different actions for different pages?

Comment: show your struts2.xml file, how u mapped the action

Comment: the struts2.xml is normal , I just set two page form with same action name,  and I don't know how to back to different page when validation failed, cause result name is same as 'input'

Comment: You can do it. But you should show us the context of it if you expect help from others.

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM thank you, that's one solution.